# java generic method fundamentals

Tags: java, generics, methods

i am running some tests to better understand java generic methods, and came across the following problem. i have the following simple class:

```
1    public class SomeClass<O extends Object> {
2    
3        O someVar;
4    
5        public SomeClass() {
6           someFunc(new Number(1));
7        }
8    
9        public void someFunc(O arg) {
10           // code
11        }
12    }
```

as it stands, the compiler does not like line 6. eclipse suggests to either cast Number instance to O, or change argument type to Number on line 9. **i would really like to avoid both if possible.** 
i know that modifying the class like so takes care of this problem:

```
1    public class SomeClass {
2    
3        O someVar;
4    
5        public SomeClass() {
6           someFunc(new Number(1));
7        }
8    
9        public <O extends Object> void someFunc(O arg) {
10           // code
11        }
12    }
```

but that brings a new problem with line 3.

so what can be done with my original code?

thank you for your time!!!

Comment: O can be anything (String, Foo, Socket, whatever object you can imagine). So calling the method with a Number as argument doesn't make sense. What are you trying to achieve, at a higher level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your first example is that you are creating a class SomeClass where O can be anything that extends Object (or Object).

For example `new SomeClass<HashMap>();`

Now the compiler will have a constructor which tries to pass Number, to a method that wants an **O** in this case a **HashMap**.

Change your constructor to take an argument `O something` which you pass to `someFunc`.

```
public SomeClass(O something) {
  someFunc(something);
}
```

If you know you want to create and pass around a **Number** your generic should instead say

```
class SomeClass<O extends Number>
```

Comment: @JB Nizet et al. i believe i understand most of what you have stated. here is what i am not clear about. if i were to instantiate my class like so: SomeClass<Object> cls= new SomeClass<Object>, then i am able to call cls.someFunc(new Number(1));. yet i am not able to make the same call from within the class itself. why is that?

Comment: @user1056027: Because if you instantiate O to be of type Object a cast from Number -> Object is valid. However inside the constructor your code must apply to all possible instantiations of O (Object, Number, HashMap, Long, etc...) and some of them are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with `<O extends Object>` you declare that O can be any type that extends Object (so really any type - you could have changed it to `<O>`).

Then your function `someFunc` is declared to accept an argument of type `O`, but then you pass  a Number. There is no guarantee that Number is O.

None of the solutions that eclipse suggests is good:

If you cast the Number to O you might get an error, since Number is not O (remember O can be anything)
If you change the argument to Number, then you can pass the private variable and I assume that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an overloaded method that excepts `Number` as an arguent.

```
public void someFunc(Number n) {
    // code
}
```